# How to use setting configuration properties in drools rule

Tags: drools, kie

I have written drools rule using Business central web, I want to use some common config properties from deployment configuration in rule logic. Is there any way to use particular config value in DRL file or how I can setup some configuration values somewhere from outside the DRL file instead of hardcoded in DRL file.
[image]

Comment: Depends on [what you're doing](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_bpm_suite/6.4/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/chap_business_central_configuration#what_can_you_configure), of course. But unless we're talking about globals (which are set up elsewhere), it your question is kind of vague -- what sort of "config value" are you looking to reference and why?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Some threshold values, which will be used in DRL file for adding condition with dto objects. For ex. If Student in class is greater than threshold value then reject it. I don't want to use hardcoded threshold values in DRL file.

Comment: Those should be globals, then.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas  Defined and initialized thresholdValue as global:
 `kcontext.getKieRuntime().setGlobal("thresholdValue", 12)` 
but not able to use it in when condition in rule
`rule "rule01 Accept/Reject Decision"
when
    $response : Class(student<thresholdValue);
then
    $response.setStatus("Accept");
end`

Comment: Did you declare `global Type thresholdValue` in your drl?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I am using Business Central, so I have declare global in gdrl file. I can print thresholdValue in then section of rule, but not able to use it in when condition.

Comment: What does "not able to use it" mean? Does it error?

Comment: I am not getting any error, but when I am using `$response : Class(student<10);` 10 as hardcoded value then I am getting proper response. When I am using global variable for comparison with same 10 value(`$response : Class(student<thresholdValue);`), I am not getting proper response.